# how do I execute a void-returning procedure in pgsql 9.1?

Tags: postgresql

If I execute the following in a file with the pgsql command, it complains that the procedure needs to be called with 'perform'. But when I try to use perform, it tells me that perform is not defined. What's the solution?

```
create or replace function waitris() returns void as 
$$
declare
    cnt integer;
begin
    loop
        select count(*) into cnt from taskflag where taskid = 'rdfdb' and state != 2;
        if cnt = 0 then   
            exit;
        end if;
        select pg_sleep(1);
    end loop;
end;
$$ 
language plpgsql;

select waitris();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no problem with how you call your function.  The error you get comes from executing it if and only if `cnt` is greater than zero.  The error you get is

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "waitris" line 9 at SQL statement
```

and it clearly states that the problem lies in the `SELECT pg_sleep(1);` line.  That is the place you should replace `SELECT` with `PERFORM`.

Otherwise your loop is futile without a `CONTINUE`.  And even if you add that, behaviour of the loop is hard to follow.  You'd better use a `WHILE` loop instead.  And still one more: as you see, I changed the variable name `count` to `cnt` for better readability.

Comment: Thanks. The psql command on my mac did not give me the accurate line number that you got.

Comment: @bmargulies: Line numbers for plpgsql error messages always count from the first line of the function body.